# How to make network requests when an iOS app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, networking, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So in my IOS app I'm getting the users login information and using that to make network requests with Alamofire and pull data from a website. What I want is a way for the app to save that login information and check in the background for any changes to the data so I can send the user a push notification. What service would I use to do this?

Comment: One approach is "background fetch" in which the app on the device will periodically [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56). The other approach is do proper remote notifications as outlined in the [Local and Remote Notifications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/).

Comment: How would I setup a server to push remote notifications and what would I have to do get that server to check the website with the users info. Could this be done with firebase?

Comment: I'd suggest you read the remote/push notifications sections of the aforementioned [Local and Remote Notifications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/). Or google push notifications tutorials and you'll get links like https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started.

Comment: @Rob Read the docs?!? Are you mad? Don't you know that you're supposed to spoon-feed the answers to everybody who asks? :grin:

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks, very helpful comment there.Glad you involved yourself in the discussion

Comment: Elmo, did you make any attempt to look up Apple's push notification service before posting your "How do I do that thing who's docs you linked?" question? If so, you neglected to mention it. "I read that link, and searched several others, but wasn't able to find any documentation on how to set up the server side of push notifications. Can you point me in the right direction?" That would be a worthy follow-up question. Your response showed **no** effort on your part, which is what elicited my sarcastic comment. Do your homework before asking others to do work for you.

Comment: @DuncanC I've been "doing my homework", just posted a question here to see if anyone could help.  Not really sure what your problem is with me trying to get help with my "homework", I only posted mine follow up question because I checked the response and the information linked wasn't really applicable to my situation since I need help with determining when the changes are made to the users account on the website. I'm so sorry for not phrasing my question properly, I now see that your sarcastic comment was well deserved. I'll try to do better next time! :grin: